# Why can't downloaded image be opened?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using ACF in Wordpress and have created an image gallery with it. Each image should have a download link so that, when clicked, the image is downloaded to the users computer. However, when I try to download, it appears to download, but then the image can't be opened. Instead, I get an error that says the image could not be opened and may be damaged or use an unrecognized file format(The image does download as a jpg).
This is the download link that I have created.

```
 <a href="<?php get_stylesheet_directory().'/webservices/download.php?filename='.$media_gallery_image['image_download_link']; ?>"
                           title="click to download this image"
                           target="_blank"
                           class="js-download"
                           download="<?php echo $media_gallery_image['image_download_link']; ?>"><?php echo $translated[$lang]['download_text']; ?></a>
```

And this is my download.php file.

```
<?php
```

$file = $_GET['file'];

download_file($file);

function download_file( $fullPath ){

```
// Must be fresh start
if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

// Required for some browsers
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

// File Exists?
if( file_exists($fullPath) ){
    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
        case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
        default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

} else
    die('File Not Found');
```

}

I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Open the downloaded file with a text or hex editor, and check if there’s any PHP error messages in there, or other output that does not actually belong into an image file.

Comment: Good thought... In doing so, what I have found is that it isn't downloading the image at all. Instead, it is downloading the HTML page. Not sure why, but that does give me somewhere to start looking.

Comment: (Does this even need a special script? If the images are not from a different origin, then a link with a `download` attribute set might already do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

Comment: That was my first attempt with this, but for some reason it didn't work. Got a Failed - No File error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I tried to over-complicate it... Finally made it work. Anyone else trying to figure this out, this is what worked for me. This is my download.php file.

```
    <?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' ) {
    if ( !is_null( $_GET['filename'] ) && !empty( $_GET['filename'] ) ) {
        $file = $_GET['filename'];
        $fname = basename( $file );
        try {
            header( 'Content-type: image/*' );
            header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname\"" );
            readfile( $file );
        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```